# Adding priority to the task permanently on Linux machine

Tags: ubuntu, debian

How do I increase the priority for a task in Debian Linux system? After a little research I found that I can increase the priority to a task using `nice` command and if I want to increase the priority for an existing task then I can use the `renice` command.

1. In some tutorials its mentioned that, nice values vary from 0 to 99, But in some tutorials states that nice values vary from -20 to 19. Which one is correct?
2. How do I increase the nice value for an GUI task? If I am doing a copy using a terminal then I can increase its priority using `nice` command, but how do I increase the priority of a task done using GUI (for example: copying files from USB to System through GUI)
3. Is it possible to set the priority of a task every time it is run? I want to set highest priority for copying files via the GUI permanently.

Comment: Nice: http://askubuntu.com/q/337444/169736

Comment: 0-99 are *real time priorities* used on real time systems.  Nice values (-20 to 19) supposedly correspond to 100 to 139, although I am not sure how that is meaningful. http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/real-time-linux-kernel-scheduler

Comment: Are you asking for CPU priorities or I/O priorities? Is kind of vague/confusing. I/O are the input/output of a filesystem (in this particular context), while CPU priority is in what order should the kernel allow the process use the CPU for processing data.

Comment: @Braiam I am asking about both I/O and CPU priority
How to increase both priority?

Comment: [Edit] your question and include that specifics. For increasing the CPU priority, the answers above works just fine. If you want to increase the I/O, you should check the answer at [ubuntu.se] that [I left for you](http://askubuntu.com/a/337458/169736).

Comment: http://and.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Nice values are from -20 to 19. From the man page (`man nice`):

> Run  COMMAND  with  an adjusted niceness, which affects process
>   scheduling.  With no COMMAND, print the current niceness. Nicenesses
>   range from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).

By default processes are started with a nice value of 0. So if you want the priority on a particular process to be high, then set its nice value to -19. If you want it to be nice, then its value would be 20.

**NOTE:** It's kind of backwards, just remember that your process is **NOT** being nice, hence the negative number.

#### List nice values

You can use the command `ps` to see what the nice value is for your processes. The command switches `-lu saml` will list all the processes for user `saml`. Here we're only showing the first 10.

```
$ ps -lu saml | head -10
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S   500  1609     1  0  80   0 - 13982 poll_s ?        00:00:01 mission-control
0 S   500  1703     1  0  80   0 - 110161 poll_s ?       00:00:01 notification-da
1 S   500  2017     1  0  80   0 - 57922 poll_s ?        00:00:11 gnome-keyring-d
4 S   500  2025  2008  0  80   0 - 27873 wait   ?        00:00:00 bash
1 S   500  2034     1  0  80   0 -  5558 poll_s ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
1 S   500  2035     1  0  80   0 -  6184 poll_s ?        00:04:06 dbus-daemon
0 S   500  2098  3240  0  80   0 - 28877 wait   pts/9    00:00:05 bash
0 S   500  2121  2025  0  80   0 - 80191 poll_s ?        00:00:03 gnome-session
0 S   500  2126     1  0  80   0 - 36231 poll_s ?        00:00:45 gconfd-2
...
```

**NOTE:* The `NI` column shows the nice values.

#### Renicing

You can `renice` any process by simply knowing its process ID. This command would increase PID 1234 to a nice of 11 (10+1):

```
$ renice +1 1234
```

You can explicitly set the nice level:

```
$ renice -n 15 1234
```

You can also set the nice level for all processes of a specific user:

```
$ renice -n 15 -u someuser
```

#### GUI

You can use the system monitor app, usually in the menus, or the command `gnome-system-monitor`, to bring up a GUI where you can change a processes nice level.

[image: sm #1]

[image: sm #2]

Comment: Great post but I think programs by default started with a nice value of 0 not 10..

Comment: I strongly think he wants the I/O priority not the CPU. Also, he crossposted over AU http://askubuntu.com/q/337444/169736

Comment: @Braiam - yeah I have to answer the question based on what he asked 8-). Since he mentioned `nice` and `renice` kind of have to answer it within that vein. I could see the I/O priority angle now that you mention it though since he's working with copying data from drive to drive. Did you ask for clarification in the comments?

Comment: @slm no, but I have kind of god-like-powers to infer this kind of vague question, but nonetheless lets ask anyway.

Comment: @Braiam nice Answer, i want to increase the priority of both cpu and i/o priority.

Comment: @Raj - did you mean to direct that comment to me (slm) or really to braiam?

Answer (score 2):

There's almost nothing you can do to increase the speed of writing to a USB drive. Although `nice` can change the amount of CPU allocated to a process, most writes to USB drives, especially flash drives, are limited by how fast the device can write the information and *not* by how much CPU is assigned.

Put another way, if the only thing the system was doing was writing to a flash drive, you'd see it take about the same amount of time to complete.